# Group array of objects by common keys, merging nested property into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have this array:

```
[
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "Jack"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "John"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Alex"}, 
    {"type": "B",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Jane"}
]
```

and I want to have a new array grouped by "**type**" and "**status**" and have the names in a list.
This is the desired output:

```
[
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name-list": ["Jack", "John"]}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name-list": ["Alex"]}, 
    {"type": "B",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name-list": ["Jane"]}
]
```

as you can see the first object of the array contains 2 names because belong to the same "**type**" and "**status**". (name-list is just an example, could also remain name, the important thing is that it should be an array of strings/objects)

I have to represent these data in an html page and so needs to be able to cycle them via JavaScript.

Comment: If performance is something that matters for your app, you may check out [the benchmark](https://jsbench.me/htkcxke91n/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may traverse your source array with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) building up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), having `type` and `status` combined as a key and respective object, with merged `name` as a value. Then extract [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) from that `Map`:

```js
const src = [{"type":"A","status":"CREATED","name":"Jack"},{"type":"A","status":"CREATED","name":"John"},{"type":"A","status":"UPDATED","name":"Alex"},{"type":"B","status":"UPDATED","name":"Jane"}],

     result = [...src
        .reduce((r, o) => {
          const key = o.type+'\ud8ff'+o.status,
                match = r.get(key)
          match ? match.name.push(o.name) : r.set(key, {...o, name: [o.name]})
          return r
        }, new Map())
        .values()
      ]
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Tha's pretty cool, how about if I have an additional integer parameter in each object, that I want to sum when grouping the names?

Comment: @andQlimax : that would be something, as simple as [that](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/QWyYrvx?editors=0012)

Answer (score 2):

I would try with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const data = [
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "Jack"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "John"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Alex"}, 
    {"type": "B",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Jane"}
];

const result = data.reduce((a, { type, status, name}) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.type === type && e.status === status);
  
  if (found) {
    found['name-list'].push(name);
  } else {
    a.push({
      type,
      status,
      ['name-list']: [name]
    });
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doing nested lookups (`.find()`'s inside `.reduce()` may slow down the performance should source array get large enough.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Agree, checked your answer, that's pretty smart, also upvoted that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "Jack"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "John"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Alex"}, 
    {"type": "B",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Jane"}
]

const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  
  acc.forEach((obj, idx) => {
      if(obj.type == cur.type && obj.status == cur.status){
          acc[idx]["name-list"].push(cur.name)
      }
  })
  
  if(!acc.some(obj => obj["name-list"].includes(cur.name))){
      acc.push({type: cur.type, status: cur.status, "name-list": [cur.name]})
  }
  
  return acc
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let arr = [
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "Jack"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "CREATED",        "name": "John"}, 
    {"type": "A",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Alex"}, 
    {"type": "B",   "status": "UPDATED",        "name": "Jane"}
];

arr = Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if(acc[`${cur.type}-${cur.status}`]) acc[`${cur.type}-${cur.status}`]["name-list"].push(cur.name)

        else {
            acc[`${cur.type}-${cur.status}`] = {type:cur.type, status:cur.status, "name-list":[cur.name]}
        }    
        return acc;
    }, {})
);

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Using hyphen as delimiter is sort of risky as you, would get merged unexpectedly objects with `{type: 'a-b', status:'c..}` and `{type: 'a', status: 'b-c'..}. You should use something more safe as delimiter, you may refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037887/11299053) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const ar = [
    { "type": "A", "status": "CREATED", "name": "Jack" },
    { "type": "A", "status": "CREATED", "name": "John" },
    { "type": "A", "status": "UPDATED", "name": "Alex" },
    { "type": "B", "status": "UPDATED", "name": "Jane" }
];
const res = Array.from(ar.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.has(c.type + c.status)) {
        a.get(c.type + c.status)['name-list'].push(c.name);
    } else {
        c['name-list'] = [c.name];
        delete c.name;
        a.set(c.type + c.status, c)
    }
    return a;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Using `type` and `status` concatenated as a Map key is somewhat dangerous, as you may get merged unexpectedly objects with `{type: 'a', status: 'bc'..}` and `{type: 'ab', status: 'c'..}`. You'd be much better off using some *safe* character as delimiter. You may refer [my ansewr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037887/11299053) for example.